# Memoir, babel[french] and @makecaption

Tags: spacing, captions, memoir, babel

I'm having a problem with the `memoir`, the `babel`, and `caption` packages: when compiling a document, the log returns the warning:

```
Package frenchb.ldf Warning: The definition of \@makecaption has been changed,
(frenchb.ldf)                frenchb will NOT customise it;
(frenchb.ldf)                reported on input line 8.
```

The thing is that the French `babel` is supposed to make `:` an active character, and as a result, put a space before and after it. But since the `@makecaption` macro is somehow redefined, the spaces are lost. How to force the behaviour for the typography around the `:` to be correct ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\begin{document}

Blah blah blah (\ref{fig:Figure})

\begin{figure}
\caption{Xxxxx}
\label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

We use the fact that a colon in French typography should be preceded and followed by a normal interword space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\captiondelim{ : }

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah (\ref{fig:Figure})

\begin{figure}
\caption{Xxxxx}
\label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Solution 2

We teach `memoir` to use the colon as redefined by `babel`; this has the advantage that it will give the normal colon if `\selectlanguage{english}` is issued or we're in the scope of `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`:
  \lowercase{\endgroup\captiondelim{~ }}%
}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah (\ref{fig:Figure})

\begin{figure}
\caption{Xxxxx}
\label{fig:Figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As regards the warning about `\@makecaption`, I'm afraid you have to keep it or use the `silence` package for removing it.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works in the MWE (btw, I prefer the second solution). It does not in my full document, but I'll run some tests and try to find what is the additional problem, I will post a comment when found. Or if I have an additional problem !